# How to close a dropdown on a mousedown

Tags: html, angularjs, dropdown, angular-ui-bootstrap

Frontend noob here, please be nice.

I have a dropdown menu using `ui.bootstrap.dropdown`. The users of my website are used to copy-paste stuff from this dropdown. In order to do so, they usually click down inside the dropdown zone, select the text they want to copy a little too fast and release the click *outside* the dropdown zone. With this behaviour, the dropdown closes before the user could copy-paste their selection.

Instead of closing the dropdown on an `mouseup` event outside of the dropdown zone, could it be a `mousedown` event that would close the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

It all has to do with the `auto-close` setting. By default, it is set to `always`. With this setting, the dropdown collapses on any outside mouseup.

To be able to control it more finely, I had to use the `auto-close="disabled"` setting coupled with `is-open="variable.isOpen"`.

Then, I created an callback on a mouse down event that is outside of the dropdown

```
    $('html').mousedown(function(e) {   
        if($scope.variable?.isOpen && !e.target?.closest('.classOfDropdown')) {
            $scope.variable.isOpen = false;
            $scope.$digest()             
        }
     });
```

I initialized `$scope.variable` inside the `on-toggle` callback.